# Program runs well in IDE but not working as .exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, forms, winforms

I wrote a program that starts minimized to system tray. On double click on the icon and pops up a login form that requires password, if the password is correct another form will open up and the login form will close.

Using the regular:

```
Settings f = new Settings();
f.Show();
this.Dispose();
Application.Exit();
```

and variation I tried cause a lot of bugs. Sometimes application would just close, sometimes there would be two iconNotify in system tray and two instances of the application, etc..

Hence, I resorted to that:

```
private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {
        new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
            new Password().ShowDialog();
        }).Start();
    });
}
```

This is in the Settings form, and it launches the Password form on a ThreadPool (So it can be reused).

I don't know why, but every time the Password thread is disposing itself (happens automatically when correct password has been entered) - Settings' form activates `FormClosing function`. Hence I resorted to that:

```
private void Settings_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { 
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.Show();
        }));
    }
}
```

This is how it looks from the Password's form view:

```
private void btn_access_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tb_password.Text == Regex.Replace(GithubAPI.ReadGithubFile("master", "Password"), @"^\s*$\n|\r", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline).TrimEnd())
    {
        //Settings form = new Settings();
        //form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        //form.Show();

        this.Dispose();
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong password, try again!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The three lines commented out make no difference while running in Visual-Studio, though running as an .exe it shows Settings' form for a split sec and then disappears.

This code as it is right now runs perfectly and as intended in Visual-Studio 2022. However, whenever I try to run it as an independent application it bugs out.

Ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what cause this to not work as an .exe, so I ended up taking a different approach.

Previously `Application.Exit();` was supposed to trigger `private void Settings_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)` which contained code for activating the form. And `this.Dispose();` in Password form was to get rid of showing multiple forms open.

This is how the code ended up:

```
private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Password form = new Password();
    if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.Show();
    }
}

private void Settings_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

And in Password form side:

```
private void btn_access_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tb_password.Text == Regex.Replace(GithubAPI.ReadGithubFile("master", "Password"), @"^\s*$\n|\r", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline).TrimEnd())
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong password, try again!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Thanks for everyone who took time to read, even if you didn't came up with a solution. Hope this will be useful to other :)